# wso2 server startup returning errors

Tags: tomcat, wso2, ldap

We have two WSO2 servers. When we start them up, we get the following errors:

> TID: [-1234] [] [2023-10-12 08:52:29,253] [] ERROR
> {org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.common.internal.SCIMCommonComponent} -
> Error occurred while setting SCIM attributes for the Admin
> org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error in adding SCIM
> metadata to the admin in tenant domain: carbon.super

and

> TID: [-1234] [] [2023-10-12 08:52:39,038] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim2.common.utils.AdminAttributeUtil} - Error occurred while updating the admin user's attributes in Tenant ID : -1234, Error : One or more attributes you are trying to add/update are not supported by underlying LDAP for user : eis_admin org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: One or more attributes you are trying to add/update are not supported by underlying LDAP for user : eis_admin

For the first one, our vendor told us that it's a known error:

> LDAP error 16 is a known issue. The root cause of it is that it is looking for a scimId attribute in the userstore, which almost no one
> has, and thus it returns this error. It will not cause the system to
> not work, but you do lose the ability to use the user-portal as it
> depends on the claim (which maps to scimId) to have a value. To fix
> it, just log into  the admin console, and modify the claim attribute
> name UserID to something else besides scimId. That something should be
> unique to the user, like uid or sAMAccountName, depending on the
> userstore of choice. Then the next time you restart, it will not
> trigger this error.

So we made this change on Tomcat for each server and it works for one but not the other. The config files for both are identical other than a few naming things for keystores, etc. that should be different. So I have no idea why one is working and the other is not. Does anyone have any thoughts on what else we need to do to correct these errors?

Thanks in advance for your assistance.